# .net Recaptcha always returns valid

Tags: c#, .net, recaptcha

I seem to be having the opposite issue to many people with recaptcha. instead of it always returning false, its always returning true:

```
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl
ID="recaptcha"
runat="server"
PublicKey="just hiding this here but i do have one generated"
PrivateKey="just hiding this here but i do have one generated"
/>
```

code behind:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(recaptcha.IsValid);
    }
```

always returns true even when i should be false. ive even tried re-downloading the latest version but the problem is still there!!!!

Comment: found the answer but SO wouldnt let me post it. need to call recaptcha.Validate(); before recaptcha.IsValid can be called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is the [`RecaptchaControl`](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/source/browse/trunk/recaptcha-plugins/dotnet/src/Recaptcha2/RecaptchaControl.cs?r=38) you are using, it looks like you need to call `Validate()` first.

If that doesn't work, maybe your app has gained sentience and answered the Recaptcha correctly. :)

Comment: Bad API design IMO. If the value is undefined it should at least throw an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: I agree. Or make `false` as default, that would be more sensible.